# virtual canvas putimagedata not working

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, off-screen

Am new to concept of virtual canvas, any idea why the below code does not work?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

          $(document).ready(function () {


              var c1 = document.createElement('canvas');
              var ctx1 = c1.getContext("2d");
              var c2 = document.getElementById('Canvas2');
              var ctx2 = c2.getContext("2d");
              c1.width = c2.width;
              c1.height = c2.height;

              img1 = new Image();
              img1.src = 'A1.png';
              img1.onload = function () {
                  ctx1.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
              };


              imgdata = ctx1.getImageData(0, 0, c2.width, c2.height);

              ctx2.putImageData(imgdata, 0, 0);


          });

      </script>  




   <canvas id="Canvas2"  style="display:block;position:absolute;background-color:transparent;border:1px solid red;">
   Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
   </canvas>
```

The concept works if i draw Rectangle or any other objects but when i am loading images it 
does not display the images loaded on virtual canvas. As below example works fine.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {


      var c1 = document.createElement('canvas');
      var ctx1 = c1.getContext("2d");
      var c2 = document.getElementById('Canvas2');
      var ctx2 = c2.getContext("2d");
      c1.width = c2.width;
      c1.height = c2.height;


      ctx1.fillRect(0, 20, 20, 20);

      imgdata = ctx1.getImageData(0, 0, c2.width, c2.height);

      ctx2.putImageData(imgdata, 0, 0);


  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must also wait with getImageData etc. until the image has loaded, so move everything that needs to be done *after* the image has loaded inside the onload handler (or wrap them in a function called from onload):

```
img1.onload = function () {

     ctx1.drawImage(this, 0, 0);

     imgdata = ctx1.getImageData(0, 0, c2.width, c2.height);

     ctx2.putImageData(imgdata, 0, 0);
};
```

If you don't then the image may not be loaded and drawn to canvas when you call getImageData which results in a blank byte array.

Comment: Brilliant. Will have to wait to accept this :-) Thanks